# How to record only computer sound without microphone?

Tags: sound

I use simple screen recorder to be able to record my computer screen including the sound of the videos I look at without recording the microphone.
If i use the default sound recorder it will record only what comes into the microphone including what comes out of the speakers what is of much less quality.
Does anyone know how I could only record the sound played inside the computer without the microphone? It is the same question as "how can I record the same way the "simple screen recorder" records but only sound (what is not an option obviously).

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try [this solution](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/record_system_sound) using `pavucontrol` program.
I tried it and it worked, however I had to go first to "Configuration" tab of `pavucontrol` and change the profile of "Built-in Audio" device from "Analog stereo output" (which has been set by default) to "Analog stereo duplex". Then the button "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" appeared in the "Recording" tab and I was able to follow the instructions.